# How to run this curl command using Net:HTTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I need to run this command over https:

```
curl -u "{user_id}:{license_key}" \
      "https://geoip.maxmind.com/geoip/v2.1/city/me?pretty"
```

I am thinking it might be possible with this

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-HTTPS

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming from your example that you're trying to do basic authentication. For a `net/http` get request that uses basic auth over SSL, here's what you can do:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

uri = URI("https://geoip.maxmind.com/geoip/v2.1/city/me?pretty")
uri.basic_auth 'user_id', 'license_key'

res = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, :use_ssl => true) { |http| 
  http.request(req) 
}
puts res.body
```

I personally find all that setup pretty cumbersome; you could also choose user-friendly gems over the standard library options. Here's how the same request would look with `httparty`:

```
require 'httparty'
auth = { :username => 'user_id', :password => 'license_key' }
res = HTTParty.get("https://geoip.maxmind.com/geoip/v2.1/city/me?pretty", 
  :basic_auth => auth)
```

Comment: For reference I ended up with something like this https://gist.github.com/funkdified/4a9ea5aada528489e60e